# Color is bleeding if AA is enabled

Tags: antialiasing

Internal Render.
There is Z-transparency material assigned to objects, which are very close to each other. Some artefacts occur if AntiAliasing is on.
If I turn off Z-transparency, or move objects a bit further, then AA works fine. But I need all options from this setup.
[image: AA 16 sample]

[image]

Comment: If you want to share files with the BlenderSE community, please use exclusively http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for that. Thanks.

Comment: @metaphor_set I don't think that the usage of that link is mandatory! Although is reccomended, because it gives permanent storage...

Comment: @m.ardito - we don't know if blend-exchange will be permanent, although I deeply hope so. GiantCowFilms created this service not without a reason. There are three additional points to yours in favor of blend-exchange. 1. It's trustworthy because it's created and maintained by s.o. of our own community who has a good reputation. 2. It's easy to use, doesn't require additional accounts and it integrates flawlessly into BlenderSE. 3. You can only upload .blend files.

Comment: @metaphor_set yes, you're right, it's a generous effort, it's defined "A long term .blend storage solution for blender.stackexchange", and it works very well, but I don't think we should ask people to use it "exclusively"...

Comment: @m.ardito - you might want to read David's answer here: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/what-to-do-with-questions-based-on-links-once-the-links-have-expired . I totally agree with him, 120%.

Comment: @m.ardito If i'm not mistaken, Blend-Exchange currently has a 30mb storage limit, which can be a problem when you need to pack fluid data or textures.

Comment: @John Silveous: of course, it's free but it has limitations, that's also why I said it should not be mandatory but, within its limits, preferrable...  for large amounts of data other methods can be useful, but most times a small file is enough to show a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use raytraced transparency, instead of Z-transparency:

[image]

does it get better?